# ¿Cómo puedo quitar doble encabezado en un data frame?

Tags: r, rstudio, datatable, rvest

Al descargar con rvest tabla de página web me salen dos encabezados ¿cómo podría quitar uno de ellos en el data table?

Esta es la tabla y quiero quitar la fila donde dice `offense four factors` y `defense four factors`:

[image: estadistica avanzada nba]

Comment: Hola @IvánVillanuevaSabalete, bienvenid@ a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad. Deberías quitar las imágenes y añadir el código directamente en la pregunta.

Comment: Hola Iván, edité un poco tu pregunta para hacerla más adecuada al sitio, revisa mis cambios. Sugerencias: 1) No compartas imágenes cuando se trata de datos o de código, en R tienes un comando muy práctico `dput(head(df))` que genera un código para reproducir eventualmente 20 filas de datos, lo agregas a tu pregunta y tenemos una muestra reproducible 2) Normalmente pedimos que se comparta que cosa has investigado o probado, en este caso, tu pregunta es sencilla, pero si fuera más compleja es fundamental compartir el código de lo que intentaste.

Comment: 3) No agregues información adicional en un comentario ni mucho menos como respuesta. 4) Has aceptado una respuesta que claramente no responde lo que has preguntado, esto no es bueno para futuros usuarios ya que consideraran la misma como una solución que en realidad no lo es. Usa el tilde de aceptación solo cuando una respuesta te ha ayudado a resolver tu pregunta. Todas estas sugerencias, están explicadas en los enlaces que te pasaron antes, es importante que los leas y entiendas como funciona SO. Saludos y buen comienzo de año.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero y principal, no hay dos encabezados, lo que llamas encabezados, son nombres de columnas o "colnames" y un `data.frame` solo tiene un único conjunto de nombres de columnas.

Seguramente `rvest` este considerando como `colname` algún encabezado de la tabla que estas leyendo que no ese el adecuado, por que de hecho, la primer fila de datos, claramente parecen ser los nombres de columnas.

Respondiendo estrictamente a tu pregunta:

```
colnames(df) <- dt[1, ] # La primer fila tiene los nombres de columnas
df <- df[-1, ]          # Borramos la primer fila
```

Ahora bien, esto deberías resolverlo antes, desde la captura de la tabla, si bien, hemos podido corregir el problema, seguramente deberás convertir las columnas por los tipos de datos apropiados ya que al capturar los nombres de columna como dato, seguramente cada columna será del tipo caracter.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, estoy  muy agradecido, era justo eso, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien que quieres decir con dos encabezados, pero si lo que quieres es borrar la primera fila de un data frame puedes probar:

```
dt <- dt[-1, ]
```

Comment: dt <- dt[-1,] me quita la que quiero conservar. Muchas gracias